# How do I turn array elements into formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, formula

Elements of the array of a math formula look this way:

```
a = [1,'+',2,'-',3,'*',4,'/',5];
```

How do I perform all the arythmetic actions between those numbers. The array elements may be different, because they are added dynamically. (Numbers are all even elements, signs are odd. The first and the last elements are always numbers.)

It would not be difficult if I didn't have to prioritize the actions `(/,*,+,-)`. I tried using `splice()` method, but something goes wrong. Maybe I can somehow sort the elements according to the math actions priority?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1,'+',2,'-',3,'*',4,'/',5];

console.log(a.join(' '), '=', eval(a.join('')));
```

<kbd>[eval() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)</kbd>

**WARNING**
[**Do not ever use eval!**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Comment: You gotta sort them by bodmas though

Comment: As you can [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+2+-+3+*+4+%2F+5), it calculates correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is. What is the correct order precedence then? Multiplication or division is the first? Multiplication is always the first.                                                                                   1-2+3*4/5 = 1.4 according to JS compliler (/ then * then - then +, no idea why it counts like that)

1-2+3*4/5 = 1.6 according to Windows Calc (I guess, it counts without any priority)

1-2+3*4/5 = -3.4 if we use the correct operator precedence (* / + -)

Comment: @smus it's not the same operation. question starts with 1+2-3 and your comment starts with 1-2+3

Comment: yeah, you're both right and yes, I used another example in the second comment. I just forgot that the precedence is based on pairs (multiplication + division and addition + subtraction). Pair over pair. If we have * and / the precedence goes to the leftmost operator. Thanks everyone! I don't know, why you downscore my question though, not everyone is a cool programmer here. All people make mistakes, sometimes we ask primitive questions :)

Comment: @smus You got downvoted because you haven't posted what you have tried so far, you were looking for someone to do it for you. However, if my answer correctly solves your problem, please mark it as **accepted**.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in stringifying the formula and executing them as it is in javascript. You can tweak the solution to fit your needs, but this will work for your case

```
var a = [1,'+',2,'-',3,'*',4,'/',5];
var b = a.join('');
eval(b);
```

Comment: It (eval) counts without arythmetic prioritization (/,*,+,-)